# Сохранение в файл .properties

Tags: php, properties

Здравствуйте.
Помогите мне пожалуйста.
Вот у меня есть код:

```
 $date = date("D M d H:i:s T y", time());

 $handler = fopen("путь к файлу .properties", "w");
  fwrite($handler, "#Minecraft server properties\n#{$date}\n");
  foreach($saveConfig AS $name => $value) {
  fwrite($handler, $name . "=" . $value . "\n");
 }

 fclose($handler);
```

При этом параметр $saveConfig имеет данные из полей.

```
 $saveConfig = $_POST['config'];
 $saveConfig['gamemode'] = intval($saveConfig['gamemode']);
```

Это поле выдает параметр на $saveConfig

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="config[gamemode]" value="1">
```

Но почему-то при сохранении запись в файл не происходит... В чем проблема?

Comment: На первый взгляд, проблема не в  коде, скорее всего проблемы с доступом к файлу - с путем или с правами

Comment: Ну права на запись у меня стоят 777... Да и путь к файлу верный.

Comment: А файл создается?

Comment: Да. Он у меня так же используется для чтения данных. У меня есть функция на чтение файлов .properties но вот сохранить почему-то не могу...

Comment: проверьте $handler на false, а результат  fwrite на не ноль

Comment: Спасибо за помощь нашел в чем была проблема.
Получается на файл у меня были права 777 а вот на папку нет. Я поставил на папку и ву-а-ля заработало.
Спасибо что так быстро среагировал на мой вопрос.

Comment: Наверное, стоит удалить вопрос

Comment: Почему? Вдруг кому поможет :D